# Adjoint functors for the power set monad

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monads

There is the power set functor, $T$, which gives raise to a monad: For a set $X$, we set $TX:=\mathcal P(X)$ and for $f:X\to Y$, we set $T(f):=S\mapsto f(S)$, where $f(S)$ denotes the direct image. The unit maps to the singleton $x\mapsto\{x\}$ and the second map gives a union, as in $\{\{a,b\},\{c\},\{\{d,e\},f\}\}\mapsto \{a,b,c,\{d,e\},f\}$. There is also the very similar list-monad, where $TX:=\bigcup_nX^n=X\cup (X\times X)\cup (X\times\dots$

What are the adjoint functor pairs $F,G$ for, so that $T=FG$ and what is the co-unit? I know there are at least "the two extremal solutions" - are they used somewhere?

Comment: In the powerset monad that I'm familiar with, the contravariant powerset functor is both the $F$ and the $G$, and the counit is the unit in $\mathbf{Set^{op}}$.

Comment: edit: For the list monad, it probably should be $X^0\cup X\cup(X\times\dots$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: I'm confused: If both $F$ and $G$ have the power set operation as object map, isn't then $T$ the twice applied power set operation?

Comment: Yes, though I've seen it referred to simply as the "powerset monad". It sounds like there are others I'm not familiar with, though.

Comment: The "twice applied power set operation" cannot be given the structure of a monad:  https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/mfps2018/preproc/paper_4.pdf    So, it's impossible to have an adjunction where both left and right adjoint are the covariant power set functor.

Comment: @JohnBaez: Ha! *Section 5: Mistakes. We shall now summarise different sources in which it has been mistakenly concluded that PP is a monad.* And then the author goes on to point the finger at a paper by himself ^^ What leads you to this old corner of the web?

Comment: I was reading that paper and wanted to make sure that the algebras of the powerset functor are complete semilattices.  By the way, it seems that while $P^2$ can't be made into a monad, we _can_ find an associative multiplication $m: P^2 P^2 \to P^2$: it's only the unit that causes problems: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2018/06/sets_of_sets_of_sets_of_sets_o.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to write $F$ for the left-adjoint. So we have $T = GF$. You can consider for $F$ the free functor from the category of sets to the category of complete semi-lattices or the free functor from the category of sets to the category of free complete semi-lattices. The functor $G$ is the forgetful functor that takes a complete semi-lattice (resp. a free complete semi-lattice) and forgets the structure to give the set of its elements.

Comment: And, for the list-monad we get the free/forgetful adjuntion between $\bf{Set}$ and [free] semigroups.

Comment: Yes, but it would be less ambiguous to write $TX = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} X^n$. Because if $TX = \bigcup_{n \geq 0} X^n$, we get the free/forgetful adjunction between Set and [free] monoids. It seems to me that usually the expression "list-monad" is used for the latter.

Comment: So $F$ maps $\{a,b,c\}$ to $\langle\mathcal{P}(\{a,b,c\}),>\rangle$, where e.g. $\{a,c\}>\{c\}$, and then $G$ on that tuple projects out the first tuple?

Comment: Yes, but it can be confusing to write $(\mathcal{P}(\{ a, b, c \} ), >)$ for an object of the category of complete semi-lattices, because morphisms have to preserve joins and not only to be monotone.

Comment: @user21929: I'm not sure what you're implying. Are you saying I should write $\ge$, rather than $>$? And btw. I just realized the relation is just $s\ge t:=t\subseteq s$, right?

Comment: You could write $(\mathcal{P}(\{ a, b, c \}), \bigcup)$ instead.

Comment: @user21929: k. Why write $\bigcup$, i.e. use a meet to set up the semi-latice, instead of a predicate like $\ge$, giving some ordering?

Comment: Example : $A = \mathcal{P}(\{ a, b \})$ and $B = \mathcal{P}(\{ a, b, c \})$. The function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ defined by $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, $f(\{ a \}) = \{ a \}$, $f(\{ b \}) = \{ a, b \}$ and $f(\{ a, b \}) = \{ a, b, c \}$ preserves $\subseteq$ but not $\bigcup$ : it is not a morphism of the category of complete semi-lattices.